# mat-icon in a mat-icon button click doesnt show the foucus correctly

Tags: html, css, button, angular-material

I have a mat-icon in a button tag with mat-icon-button attribute. but when I click on the icon, the focus circle is somewhere else. I want it to be on the icon exactly. here are the codes: 
HTML

```
<button mat-icon-button class="button">
  <mat-icon class="menu">menu</mat-icon>
</button>
```

CSS

```
    .menu {
  width: 18px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 0px
}

.button {
  padding-left: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

[image: and this is what happens]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
.button{
position:relative;
}

.menu{
position:absolute;
top:5px; //change the value to set it in center
left:5px; //change the value to set it in center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is present in you button css (padding-left: 24px)

**Correct version:**

```
 .menu {
   width: 18px;
   height: 12px;
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 30px;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }

 .button {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: but I need the 24px space from left